# ReferenceError: SomeName is not defined (exposing class in Haxe)

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, tdd, mocha.js, haxe

I am a beginner of Haxe. I tried to do **FizzBuzz TDD**. I used **Mocha** and **expect.js**.
I exposed the Haxe class by `@:expose("SomeName")` to be able to be seen from test.

However, the test cannot find FizzBuzz class.

**FizzBuzz.hx**

```
package ;

@:expose("SomeName")
class FizzBuzz{

    public function new() {

    }

    public function put(n : Int) : String {
        if (n == 3) {
            return "Fizz";
        }
        else {
            return Std.string(n);
        }
    }
}
```

**Main.hx**

```
package ;

import js.Lib;

class Main {

    static function main() {
        var f = new FizzBuzz();
        for (i in 1...100) {
            f.put(i);
        }

    }

}
```

**fizzbuzz.js**

```
(function ($hx_exports) { "use strict";
var FizzBuzz = $hx_exports.SomeName = function() {
};
FizzBuzz.prototype = {
    put: function(n) {
        if(n == 3) return "Fizz"; else if(n == null) return "null"; else return "" + n;
    }
};
var Main = function() { };
Main.main = function() {
    var f = new FizzBuzz();
    var _g = 1;
    while(_g < 100) {
        var i = _g++;
        f.put(i);
    }
};
Main.main();
})(typeof window != "undefined" ? window : exports);
```

**fizzbuzztest.coffee**

```
expect = require 'expect.js'
fizzbuzz   = require '../bin/fizzbuzz.js'

describe 'fizzbuzz', ->
    it 'put Fizz when 3 is given', ->
        f = new SomeName()
        result = f.put(3)
        expect(result).to.be(3)
```

**Error Message**

```
fizzbuzz put Fizz when 3 is given
    ✘ failed
        ReferenceError: SomeName is not defined
```

How can I find the FizzBuzz class from test code? Thank you for your help.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but a more straight forward approach might be to use a native Haxe BDD library.  There's a new one called "Buddy" that I quite like so far: https://github.com/ciscoheat/buddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fizzbuzz   = require '../bin/fizzbuzz.js'`

SomeName was exported to your exports, so it is currenly in `fizzbuzz.SomeName` and of course there is no variable named `SomeName`(and so it says to you).

Actually, your problem have nothing to do with haxe, it's you just incorrect coffeescript code you written, it wouldn't work with any native js module too.